# How do I duplicate or clone a sprite?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make my own little flappy bird game and I will like to know how to create the pipes.

I have tried several `SKAction.moveTo(x: "Dosen't matter", duration: "Dosen't matter")` and I want to know how to keep running this forever loop until the bird dies.

```
pipe.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: <#T##CGFloat#>, duration: <#T##TimeInterval#>))
```

I don't know how to make it go forever. I just goes once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use repeatForever

```
 pipe.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.moveTo(x: <#T##CGFloat#>, duration: <#T##TimeInterval#>)))
```

Comment: Yeah. But it won't get back to where it started.

Comment: When I say it I mean the pipe

Comment: Nvm... I figured it out.

Comment: Make sure to manually call pipe.removeAllActions() before you deinit the scene otherwise it will result in a scene memory leak.